# Get selected data from plotly parallel coordinates plot in streamlit app

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I'm building a streamlit app and I would like to have a parallel coordinates plot with a table below it showing the entries that were selected.

This is the sample code for a paralell coordinates plot, within streamlit:

```
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.parallel_coordinates(df, color="species_id",
                              dimensions=['sepal_width', 'sepal_length', 'petal_width',
                                          'petal_length'],
                              color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.Tealrose,
                              color_continuous_midpoint=2)

st.plotly_chart(fig)

if st.button('show selection'):
    st.text(fig['data'])
    tmp_df = df # Do something here to get the selected data
    st.dataframe(tmp_df)
```

[Some posts regarding this topic are using dash to build their platform](https://community.plotly.com/t/get-selected-data-in-a-parallel-coordinates-chart-to-update-table-resolved/24020/4), that that is not my case. I am using streamlit and don't fully understand how they are achieving this. The variable "data" from my figure does not update when selecting data, in streamlit or a test notebook, and I am not used to working with callbacks in python.

I would appreciate help understading how to make this work, or an alternative plotting library which would make this possible

[image: desired outcome]

Answer (score 0):

The button does not have a selection value, so an input box must be provided to obtain a selection value, for example. In this data example, there are three choices, so a checkbox is used to allow selection. The default graph is a graph with all categories selected. If any checkbox is deselected, the graph and data are shown with the remaining data. If you want to start with unselected, set the checkbox value to false.

```
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

df = px.data.iris()

def  get_parallel_coodi(df):
    fig = px.parallel_coordinates(df, color="species_id",
                                dimensions=['sepal_width', 'sepal_length', 'petal_width',
                                            'petal_length'],
                                color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.Tealrose,
                                color_continuous_midpoint=2)
    #fig.show()
    return fig

st.write('#### Species_id')
cols = st.columns(3)

category_list = df['species_id'].unique()
category = [None]* len(category_list)
for i,s in enumerate(category_list):
    with cols[i]:
        category[i] = st.checkbox(str(s), value=True)
        #st.write(category)

dff = df[df['species_id'].isin(category_list[category])].reset_index(drop=True)
fig = get_parallel_coodi(dff)
st.plotly_chart(fig, theme="streamlit", use_container_width=True)
st.dataframe(dff)
```

[image]